# C++ Stack-allocated object assignment and destructor call

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what appears to be some weird behaviour when assigning a new value to an object allocated on stack (the destructor gets called twice for the same data set). I'll just start with the code snippet and its output:

```
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(const string& name) : m_name(name) {
            log("constructor");
        }
        ~Foo() {
            log("destructor");
        }
        void hello() {
            log("hello");
        }
    private:
        string m_name;
        void log(const string& msg) {
            cout << "Foo." << this << " [" << m_name << "] " << msg << endl;
        }
    };

    int main() {

        {
            Foo f {"f1"};
            f.hello();

            f = Foo {"f2"};
            f.hello();
        }
        cout << "scope end" << endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a58 [f1] constructor
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a58 [f1] hello
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a18 [f2] constructor
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a18 [f2] destructor
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a58 [f2] hello
    Foo.0x7fff58c66a58 [f2] destructor
    scope end
```

What I expected to happen:

- 0x...58 gets created/initialised on stack
- 0x...18 gets created/initialised on stack
- Foo destructor gets called on 0x...58 (with f1 data)
- Foo destructor gets called on 0x...18 (with f2 data)

What actually happens:

- 0x...58 gets created/initialised on stack
- 0x...18 gets created/initialised on stack
- *data from 0x...18 (f2) gets copied onto 0x...58*
- *Foo destructor gets called on 0x...18 (with f2 data)*
- *Foo destructor gets called on 0x...58 (also with f2 data)*

So in the end, **Foo destructor gets called twice for the same data (f2)**. Clearly I'm missing something about how this works internally, so can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You won't see a message for an `"f1"` destructor because you've copied a temporary object that changes the name held by `f` from `"f1"` to `"f2"`.  Thus, you see the temporary `"f2"` destruct first and then the original instance (which is now named `"f2"`) destruct. Note that the data is not the same; it is a copy with the same value.

Comment: If your class has a destructor, it should almost certainly also have a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: And (probably) a move constructor and move assignment operator (the "rule of five").

Answer (score 5):

Your instance **f** is being assigned a *copy* of Foo {"f2"}, it's not a *new* construction.

Add the following **operator=** override to illustrate what is actually happening.

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo& other) {
    cout << "Foo::operator=(const Foo& other)" << endl;
    m_name = other.m_name;  
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Before creating the second `Foo` object, you only have one object at address `0x..58`.

```
Address: 0x..58            Data: { m_name "f1" }
Address: 0x..18            Data: unknown
```

The line `f = Foo {"f2"};` first creates a new Foo object whose `m_name` value is `"f2"`, and stores it at address `0x..18`. Then it assigns this object to the variable `f`.

This assignment doesn't destroy the previously existing object in `f`, it only copies the data members into it. Since Foo objects have only one data member, `m_name`, the assignment just copies the second object's `m_name` into the first.

```
Address: 0x..58            Data: { m_name "f2" }
Address: 0x..18            Data: { m_name "f2" }
```

Then the destructors are called for each of these objects. The output doesn't mean the same object is destroyed twice, it just means that both objects have the same `m_name`.